# Spring-integration ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice unable to evaluate the failureExpression

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

Following a question I made yesterday, I found some issues with the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` because it isn't working as I expected.

I tried the [doc example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/handler-advice.html#expression-advice) and my expectation were to get two `AdviceMessage`: one saying "good was successful" and another one saying "bad was bad, with reason..." but when I run the code I get an AdviceMessage and an ErrorMessage.

```
AdviceMessage [payload=good was successful, headers={id=2eb612ea-d3cd-f853-3295-236505a130f3, timestamp=1611307975199}, inputMessage=GenericMessage [payload=good, headers={id=725e89ea-be09-7534-1b29-5c7412a99a79, timestamp=1611307975196}]]
ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice$MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException: Handler Failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not invoke the method 'public java.lang.Object com.example.demo.EerhaApplication$$Lambda$299/0x00000008401d7040.handle(java.lang.Object,org.springframework.messaging.MessageHeaders)', failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=bad, headers={id=7639425f-7676-d521-5994-4c74e5b09f4a, timestamp=1611307975200}], headers={id=aaa07286-4bc3-71e5-09fb-6b55a46e0ecf, timestamp=1611307975201}]
```

Apparently an Exception is always thrown evaluating the failureExpression never getting the desired result.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.4.2 but I've also tried with older versions, having always the same behaviour.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

We need to see your code for this `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice`, but any way, the `AdviceMessage` is sent only in case of successful evaluation of the `onSuccessExpression`:

```
if (evalResult != null && this.successChannel != null) {
    AdviceMessage<?> resultMessage = new AdviceMessage<>(evalResult, message);
    this.messagingTemplate.send(this.successChannel, resultMessage);
}
```

When you `MessageHandler` fails (even if `onSuccessExpression` fails), we go to this branch:

```
catch (RuntimeException e) {
        Exception actualException = unwrapExceptionIfNecessary(e);
        if (this.onFailureExpression != null) {
            Object evalResult = evaluateFailureExpression(message, actualException);
            if (this.returnFailureExpressionResult) {
                return evalResult;
            }
        }
```

and there we send an `ErrorMessage`:

```
 if (evalResult != null && this.failureChannel != null) {
        MessagingException messagingException =
                new MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException(message, "Handler Failed",
                        unwrapThrowableIfNecessary(exception), evalResult);
        ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(messagingException);
        this.messagingTemplate.send(this.failureChannel, errorMessage);
    }
```

So, what you show is really an expected behavior.

Therefore need to see you config and understand what is your expectation in both cases.

Comment: Thank you Artem, the code is the example I found in the doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/handler-advice.html#expression-advice . I expected to have a message saying "payload was bad for reason..." while it seems that the onErrorExpression in never evaluated (or it is but always fail)

Comment: Well, that `"payload was bad for reason..."` is a part of `MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException`, which is not visible just as is when we use `System.out::println`, your error flow must take the `evaluationResult` property of that `MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException` to be clear.

Comment: got it, thanks! A bit intricated but I got the expression printed with:  System.out.println(((ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException)m.getPayload()).getEvaluationResult());

Comment: Yes, a SpEL expression would be much simple though `"payload.evaluationResult"` :wink:

Answer (score 0):

in order to get the the String "bad was bad, with reason..." printed this was my solution:

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow failure() {
  return f -> f.handle(m -> {
    System.out.println(((ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException)m.getPayload()).getEvaluationResult());
  });
}
```